# Can we have Lily-Indexer sync HBase and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, hbase

As we all know Lily Indexer does a good job of keeping HBase and SOLR in Sync.

Is there a way or tool that we can have same thing between HBase and ElasticSearch ?

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/search_hbase_batch_indexer.html

Thanks.